# Standard Bar code device

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I have a library system project and I'd like to ask if there is a standard bar code device for all books (new and old ones). thanks for any helpful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to read the [ISBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number), they use an [EAN-13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number_(EAN)) barcode.

[image: ISBN EAN-13 Barcode]

Most 1D barcode readers would work with this. (1D referring to the barcode having only 1 dimension, usually data plotted along the X axis. 2D Barcodes include Data Matrix and QR Code, where the data is plotted along both the X and Y axis).

Barcode scanners now are typically USB and input data as if they were a standard keyboard. You can also get scanners which work over TCP/IP, and likely other technologies such as Bluetooth. When you look for devices, check the barcode types it covers, as stated most all of them will support EAN-13. You don't need a 2D barcode reader, these are usually imaging devices and can cost significantly more, as well as having a higher latency (Not that this should matter unless you are dealing with very high volumes, very quickly).

Comment: Hi Jonno, is 1D standard for all the books with ISBN? I'll do further research for that. thanks for the answer! vote up. oops I can't vote up due to low rep.

Comment: @FrancisSaul I've amended my answer with more detail.